# How to define multiple entities?

Tags: java, sqlite, gradle, android-room, androidx

I'm currently building an Inventory Management App for Point-of-Sales activities. Here, I am required to include a database feature with 3 tables: *item*, *invoice*, and *cart*. According to the official Android documentation (https://developer.android.com/training/data-storage/sqlite), the use of the Room library is highly advisable because of the drawback without it: no compile-time verification, lots of boilerplate code. With that, I decided to give it a try.

Firstly, I started to test the Room implementation using one table. In order to define *item*, I created 3 objects :*Item* class, *ItemDao* interface, and *POSDatabase* class. As a result, all queries run successfully.

However, when I tried introducing another entity, *invoice*, it produces error on the *Run build* and the *Java compiler* during a Make. I attempted to fix the problem by migrating the database as recommended by Suslov (https://medium.com/@kirillsuslov/how-to-add-more-that-one-entity-in-room-5cc3743219c0). Despite the editing though, similar errors are produced.

Finally, I would like to know what is a proper way of defining more than one tables using Room. But, besides this, I also need some enlightenment regarding the errors. Thank you for your attention.

**Attempted Workaround**

According to Suslov, a migration is required in order to introduce additional tables into the database. The source also mentions that the definition of the migration is to be placed inside the RoomDatabase inheritor (*POSDatabase*).

```
static final Migration MIGRATION_1_2 = new Migration(1, 2) {
        @Override
        public void migrate(SupportSQLiteDatabase database) {
            database.execSQL("CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `invoice` (`invoice_id` VARCHAR, "
                    + "`terminal_no` VARCHAR NOT NULL, `cashier_name` TEXT,  PRIMARY KEY(`invoice_id`))");
        }
    };
```

*MIGRATION_1_2* is then included during the call:

```
Room.databaseBuilder(context.getApplicationContext(),
                                    POSDatabase.class,
                                 "pos_database").addMigrations(MIGRATION_1_2).build();
```

Item.java

```
package com.example.qrreceipt;

import androidx.annotation.NonNull;
import androidx.room.ColumnInfo;
import androidx.room.Entity;
import androidx.room.PrimaryKey;

@Entity(tableName = "item")
public class Item {
    @PrimaryKey
    @NonNull
    @ColumnInfo(name = "item_id")
    private String item_id;

    @ColumnInfo(name = "description")
    private String description;

    @ColumnInfo(name = "price")
    private double price;

    public Item() { }

    @NonNull
    public String getItem_id() {
        return item_id;
    }

    public String getDescription() {
        return description;
    }

    public double getPrice() {
        return price;
    }

    public void setItem_id(@NonNull String item_id) {
        this.item_id = item_id;
    }

    public void setDescription(String description) {
        this.description = description;
    }

    public void setPrice(double price) {
        this.price = price;
    }
}
```

ItemDao.java

```
package com.example.qrreceipt;

import androidx.room.Dao;
import androidx.room.Insert;
import androidx.room.Query;
import androidx.room.Update;

import java.util.List;

@Dao
public interface ItemDao {
    @Insert
    void insertItem(Item item);

    @Update
    void updateItem(Item item);

    @Query("SELECT * FROM item WHERE item_id = :item_id")
    List<Item> findItem(String item_id);

    @Query("SELECT * FROM item")
    List<Item> getAllItems();

    @Query("DELETE FROM item WHERE item_id = :item_id")
    void deleteItem(String item_id);
}
```

POSDatabase.java

```
package com.example.qrreceipt;

import android.content.Context;

import androidx.room.Database;
import androidx.room.Room;
import androidx.room.RoomDatabase;
import androidx.room.migration.Migration;
import androidx.sqlite.db.SupportSQLiteDatabase;

@Database(entities = {Item.class, Invoice.class}, version = 2, exportSchema = false)
public abstract class POSDatabase extends RoomDatabase {
    public abstract ItemDao getItemDAO();
    public abstract InvoiceDao getInvoiceDAO();

    private static POSDatabase INSTANCE;

    static final Migration MIGRATION_1_2 = new Migration(1, 2) {
        @Override
        public void migrate(SupportSQLiteDatabase database) {
            database.execSQL("CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `invoice` (`invoice_id` VARCHAR, "
                    + "`terminal_no` VARCHAR NOT NULL, `cashier_name` TEXT,  PRIMARY KEY(`invoice_id`))");
        }
    };

    static POSDatabase getDatabase(final Context context) {
        if (INSTANCE == null) {
            synchronized (POSDatabase.class) {
                if (INSTANCE == null) {
                    INSTANCE =
                            Room.databaseBuilder(context.getApplicationContext(),
                                    POSDatabase.class,
                                 "pos_database").addMigrations(MIGRATION_1_2).build();

                }
            }
        }
        return INSTANCE;
    }
}
```

Invoice.java

```
package com.example.qrreceipt;

import androidx.annotation.NonNull;
import androidx.room.ColumnInfo;
import androidx.room.Entity;
import androidx.room.PrimaryKey;

@Entity(tableName = "invoice")
public class Invoice {
    @PrimaryKey
    @NonNull
    @ColumnInfo(name = "invoice_id")
    private String invoice_id;

    //private Date date;

    @ColumnInfo(name = "terminal_no")
    private String terminal_no;

    @ColumnInfo(name = "cashier_name")
    private String cashier_name;

    public Invoice() { }

    @NonNull
    public String getInvoice_id() {
        return invoice_id;
    }

    public String getTerminal_no() {
        return terminal_no;
    }

    public String getCashier_name() {
        return cashier_name;
    }

    public void setInvoice_id(@NonNull String invoice_id) {
        this.invoice_id = invoice_id;
    }

    public void setTerminal_no(String terminal_no) {
        this.terminal_no = terminal_no;
    }

    public void setCashier_name(String cashier_name) {
        this.cashier_name = cashier_name;
    }
}
```

InvoiceDao.java

```
package com.example.qrreceipt;

import androidx.room.Dao;
import androidx.room.Insert;
import androidx.room.Query;
import androidx.room.Update;

import java.util.List;

@Dao
public interface InvoiceDao {
    @Insert
    void insertInvoice(Invoice invoice);

    @Update
    void updateInvoice(Invoice invoice);

    @Query("SELECT * FROM invoice WHERE invoice_id = :invoice_id")
    List<Item> findInvoice(String invoice_id);

    @Query("SELECT * FROM invoice")
    List<Item> getAllInvoices();

    @Query("DELETE FROM invoice WHERE invoice_id = :invoice_id")
    void deleteInvoice(String invoice_id);
}
```

Run build > Run tasks > :app:compileDebugJavaWithJavac

> org.gradle.api.tasks.TaskExecutionException: Execution failed for task
>   ':app:compileDebugJavaWithJavac'.     at
>   org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.execute(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:95)
>     at
>   org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ResolveTaskOutputCachingStateExecuter.execute(ResolveTaskOutputCachingStateExecuter.java:91)
>     at
>   org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ValidatingTaskExecuter.execute(ValidatingTaskExecuter.java:57)
>     at
>   org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.SkipEmptySourceFilesTaskExecuter.execute(SkipEmptySourceFilesTaskExecuter.java:119)
>     at
>   org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ResolvePreviousStateExecuter.execute(ResolvePreviousStateExecuter.java:43)
>     at
>   org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.CleanupStaleOutputsExecuter.execute(CleanupStaleOutputsExecuter.java:93)
>     at
>   org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.FinalizePropertiesTaskExecuter.execute(FinalizePropertiesTaskExecuter.java:45)
>     at
>   org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ResolveTaskArtifactStateTaskExecuter.execute(ResolveTaskArtifactStateTaskExecuter.java:94)
>     at
>   org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.SkipTaskWithNoActionsExecuter.execute(SkipTaskWithNoActionsExecuter.java:56)
>     at
>   org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.SkipOnlyIfTaskExecuter.execute(SkipOnlyIfTaskExecuter.java:55)
>     at
>   org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.CatchExceptionTaskExecuter.execute(CatchExceptionTaskExecuter.java:36)
>     at
>   org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.EventFiringTaskExecuter$1.executeTask(EventFiringTaskExecuter.java:67)
>     at
>   org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.EventFiringTaskExecuter$1.call(EventFiringTaskExecuter.java:52)
>     at
>   org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.EventFiringTaskExecuter$1.call(EventFiringTaskExecuter.java:49)
>     at
>   org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor$CallableBuildOperationWorker.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:315)
>     at
>   org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor$CallableBuildOperationWorker.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:305)
>     at
>   org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:175)
>     at
>   org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.call(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:101)
>     at
>   org.gradle.internal.operations.DelegatingBuildOperationExecutor.call(DelegatingBuildOperationExecutor.java:36)
>     at
>   org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.EventFiringTaskExecuter.execute(EventFiringTaskExecuter.java:49)
>     at
>   org.gradle.execution.plan.LocalTaskNodeExecutor.execute(LocalTaskNodeExecutor.java:43)
>     at
>   org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskExecutionGraph$InvokeNodeExecutorsAction.execute(DefaultTaskExecutionGraph.java:355)
>     at
>   org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskExecutionGraph$InvokeNodeExecutorsAction.execute(DefaultTaskExecutionGraph.java:343)
>     at
>   org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskExecutionGraph$BuildOperationAwareExecutionAction.execute(DefaultTaskExecutionGraph.java:336)
>     at
>   org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskExecutionGraph$BuildOperationAwareExecutionAction.execute(DefaultTaskExecutionGraph.java:322)
>     at
>   org.gradle.execution.plan.DefaultPlanExecutor$ExecutorWorker$1.execute(DefaultPlanExecutor.java:134)
>     at
>   org.gradle.execution.plan.DefaultPlanExecutor$ExecutorWorker$1.execute(DefaultPlanExecutor.java:129)
>     at
>   org.gradle.execution.plan.DefaultPlanExecutor$ExecutorWorker.execute(DefaultPlanExecutor.java:202)
>     at
>   org.gradle.execution.plan.DefaultPlanExecutor$ExecutorWorker.executeNextNode(DefaultPlanExecutor.java:193)
>     at
>   org.gradle.execution.plan.DefaultPlanExecutor$ExecutorWorker.run(DefaultPlanExecutor.java:129)
>     at
>   org.gradle.internal.concurrent.ExecutorPolicy$CatchAndRecordFailures.onExecute(ExecutorPolicy.java:63)
>     at
>   org.gradle.internal.concurrent.ManagedExecutorImpl$1.run(ManagedExecutorImpl.java:46)
>     at
>   java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
>     at
>   java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
>     at
>   org.gradle.internal.concurrent.ThreadFactoryImpl$ManagedThreadRunnable.run(ThreadFactoryImpl.java:55)
>     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745) Caused by:
>   org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.compile.CompilationFailedException:
>   Compilation failed; see the compiler error output for details.    at
>   org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.compile.JdkJavaCompiler.execute(JdkJavaCompiler.java:52)
>     at
>   org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.compile.JdkJavaCompiler.execute(JdkJavaCompiler.java:36)
>     at
>   org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.compile.NormalizingJavaCompiler.delegateAndHandleErrors(NormalizingJavaCompiler.java:100)
>     at
>   org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.compile.NormalizingJavaCompiler.execute(NormalizingJavaCompiler.java:52)
>     at
>   org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.compile.NormalizingJavaCompiler.execute(NormalizingJavaCompiler.java:38)
>     at
>   org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.compile.AnnotationProcessorDiscoveringCompiler.execute(AnnotationProcessorDiscoveringCompiler.java:51)
>     at
>   org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.compile.AnnotationProcessorDiscoveringCompiler.execute(AnnotationProcessorDiscoveringCompiler.java:37)
>     at
>   org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.compile.CleaningJavaCompilerSupport.execute(CleaningJavaCompilerSupport.java:39)
>     at
>   org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.compile.incremental.IncrementalCompilerFactory$2.execute(IncrementalCompilerFactory.java:110)
>     at
>   org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.compile.incremental.IncrementalCompilerFactory$2.execute(IncrementalCompilerFactory.java:106)
>     at
>   org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.compile.incremental.IncrementalResultStoringCompiler.execute(IncrementalResultStoringCompiler.java:59)
>     at
>   org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.compile.incremental.IncrementalResultStoringCompiler.execute(IncrementalResultStoringCompiler.java:43)
>     at
>   org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.compile.CompileJavaBuildOperationReportingCompiler$2.call(CompileJavaBuildOperationReportingCompiler.java:59)
>     at
>   org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.compile.CompileJavaBuildOperationReportingCompiler$2.call(CompileJavaBuildOperationReportingCompiler.java:51)
>     at
>   org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor$CallableBuildOperationWorker.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:315)
>     at
>   org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor$CallableBuildOperationWorker.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:305)
>     at
>   org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:175)
>     at
>   org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.call(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:101)
>     at
>   org.gradle.internal.operations.DelegatingBuildOperationExecutor.call(DelegatingBuildOperationExecutor.java:36)
>     at
>   org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.compile.CompileJavaBuildOperationReportingCompiler.execute(CompileJavaBuildOperationReportingCompiler.java:51)
>     at
>   org.gradle.api.tasks.compile.JavaCompile.performCompilation(JavaCompile.java:154)
>     at
>   org.gradle.api.tasks.compile.JavaCompile.compile(JavaCompile.java:122)
>     at
>   com.android.build.gradle.tasks.AndroidJavaCompile.compile(AndroidJavaCompile.kt:214)
>     at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)  at
>   sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
>     at
>   sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
>     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)     at
>   org.gradle.internal.reflect.JavaMethod.invoke(JavaMethod.java:73)     at
>   org.gradle.api.internal.project.taskfactory.IncrementalTaskAction.doExecute(IncrementalTaskAction.java:47)
>     at
>   org.gradle.api.internal.project.taskfactory.StandardTaskAction.execute(StandardTaskAction.java:41)
>     at
>   org.gradle.api.internal.project.taskfactory.StandardTaskAction.execute(StandardTaskAction.java:28)
>     at
>   org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter$2.run(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:284)
>     at
>   org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor$RunnableBuildOperationWorker.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:301)
>     at
>   org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor$RunnableBuildOperationWorker.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:293)
>     at
>   org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:175)
>     at
>   org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.run(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:91)
>     at
>   org.gradle.internal.operations.DelegatingBuildOperationExecutor.run(DelegatingBuildOperationExecutor.java:31)
>     at
>   org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.executeAction(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:273)
>     at
>   org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.executeActions(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:258)
>     at
>   org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.access$200(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:67)
>     at
>   org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter$TaskExecution.execute(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:145)
>     at
>   org.gradle.internal.execution.impl.steps.ExecuteStep.execute(ExecuteStep.java:49)
>     at
>   org.gradle.internal.execution.impl.steps.CancelExecutionStep.execute(CancelExecutionStep.java:34)
>     at
>   org.gradle.internal.execution.impl.steps.TimeoutStep.executeWithoutTimeout(TimeoutStep.java:69)
>     at
>   org.gradle.internal.execution.impl.steps.TimeoutStep.execute(TimeoutStep.java:49)
>     at
>   org.gradle.internal.execution.impl.steps.CatchExceptionStep.execute(CatchExceptionStep.java:33)
>     at
>   org.gradle.internal.execution.impl.steps.CreateOutputsStep.execute(CreateOutputsStep.java:50)
>     at
>   org.gradle.internal.execution.impl.steps.SnapshotOutputStep.execute(SnapshotOutputStep.java:43)
>     at
>   org.gradle.internal.execution.impl.steps.SnapshotOutputStep.execute(SnapshotOutputStep.java:29)
>     at
>   org.gradle.internal.execution.impl.steps.CacheStep.executeWithoutCache(CacheStep.java:134)
>     at
>   org.gradle.internal.execution.impl.steps.CacheStep.lambda$execute$3(CacheStep.java:83)
>     at java.util.Optional.orElseGet(Optional.java:267)  at
>   org.gradle.internal.execution.impl.steps.CacheStep.execute(CacheStep.java:82)
>     at
>   org.gradle.internal.execution.impl.steps.CacheStep.execute(CacheStep.java:36)
>     at
>   org.gradle.internal.execution.impl.steps.PrepareCachingStep.execute(PrepareCachingStep.java:33)
>     at
>   org.gradle.internal.execution.impl.steps.StoreSnapshotsStep.execute(StoreSnapshotsStep.java:38)
>     at
>   org.gradle.internal.execution.impl.steps.StoreSnapshotsStep.execute(StoreSnapshotsStep.java:23)
>     at
>   org.gradle.internal.execution.impl.steps.SkipUpToDateStep.executeBecause(SkipUpToDateStep.java:96)
>     at
>   org.gradle.internal.execution.impl.steps.SkipUpToDateStep.lambda$execute$0(SkipUpToDateStep.java:89)
>     at java.util.Optional.map(Optional.java:215)    at
>   org.gradle.internal.execution.impl.steps.SkipUpToDateStep.execute(SkipUpToDateStep.java:52)
>     at
>   org.gradle.internal.execution.impl.steps.SkipUpToDateStep.execute(SkipUpToDateStep.java:36)
>     at
>   org.gradle.internal.execution.impl.DefaultWorkExecutor.execute(DefaultWorkExecutor.java:34)
>     at
>   org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.execute(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:91)
>     ... 35 more

Java compiler: (2 errors, 2 warnings)

> Warning: The query returns some columns [invoice_id, terminal_no,
>   cashier_name] which are not used by com.example.qrreceipt.Item. You
>   can use @ColumnInfo annotation on the fields to specify the mapping.
>   com.example.qrreceipt.Item has some fields [item_id, description,
>   price] which are not returned by the query. If they are not supposed
>   to be read from the result, you can mark them with @Ignore annotation.
>   You can suppress this warning by annotating the method with
>   @SuppressWarnings(RoomWarnings.CURSOR_MISMATCH). Columns returned by
>   the query: invoice_id, terminal_no, cashier_name. Fields in
>   com.example.qrreceipt.Item: item_id, description, price.
>
> Error: The columns returned by the query does not have the fields
>   [item_id,price] in com.example.qrreceipt.Item even though they are
>   annotated as non-null or primitive. Columns returned by the query:
>   [invoice_id,terminal_no,cashier_name]
>
> Warning: The query returns some columns [invoice_id, terminal_no,
>   cashier_name] which are not used by com.example.qrreceipt.Item. You
>   can use @ColumnInfo annotation on the fields to specify the mapping.
>   com.example.qrreceipt.Item has some fields [item_id, description,
>   price] which are not returned by the query. If they are not supposed
>   to be read from the result, you can mark them with @Ignore annotation.
>   You can suppress this warning by annotating the method with
>   @SuppressWarnings(RoomWarnings.CURSOR_MISMATCH). Columns returned by
>   the query: invoice_id, terminal_no, cashier_name. Fields in
>   com.example.qrreceipt.Item: item_id, description, price.
>
> Error: error: The columns returned by the query does not have the
>   fields [item_id,price] in com.example.qrreceipt.Item even though they
>   are annotated as non-null or primitive. Columns returned by the query:
>   [invoice_id,terminal_no,cashier_name]

Answer (score 0):

## Initial Issue

Your current issue is that your are trying to get Items from the Invoices table.

That's what the following is saying :-

> Error: The columns returned by the query does not have the fields
> [item_id,price] in com.example.qrreceipt.Item even though they are
> annotated as non-null or primitive. Columns returned by the query:
> [invoice_id,terminal_no,cashier_name]

To Fix this issue change **InvoiceDao** to use :-

```
@Query("SELECT * FROM invoice WHERE invoice_id = :invoice_id")
List<Invoice> findInvoice(String invoice_id);


@Query("SELECT * FROM invoice")
List<Invoice> getAllInvoices();
```

(i.e. return `List<Invoice>` rather than `List<Item>`)

## Other Issues

After fixing the above you would then encounter issues due to the table definition not matching the entity.

In that :-

1. You have **@NonNull** for **invoice_id** but you don't have **NOT NULL** coded in the SQL (they must match/compliment each other).
2. You have **NOT NULL** coded in the SQL for the **terminal_no but** do not have @NonNull in Invoice@Dao (again they must compliment each other)
3. You have VARCHAR coded in the SQL for both **invoice_id** and **terminal_no** you cannot have **VARCHAR** the column type's MUST be **TEXT** (you are quite limited to the column types that can be specified when using room).

Using :-

```
database.execSQL("CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `invoice` (`invoice_id` TEXT NOT NULL, "
                + "`terminal_no` TEXT NOT NULL, `cashier_name` TEXT,  PRIMARY KEY(`invoice_id`))");
```

along with :-

```
@Entity(tableName = "invoice")
public class Invoice {
    @PrimaryKey
    @NonNull
    @ColumnInfo(name = "invoice_id")
    private String invoice_id;

    //private Date date;

    @NonNull
    @ColumnInfo(name = "terminal_no")
    private String terminal_no;

    @ColumnInfo(name = "cashier_name")
    private String cashier_name;

    public Invoice() { }

    @NonNull
    public String getInvoice_id() {
        return invoice_id;
    }

    public String getTerminal_no() {
        return terminal_no;
    }

    public String getCashier_name() {
        return cashier_name;
    }

    public void setInvoice_id(@NonNull String invoice_id) {
        this.invoice_id = invoice_id;
    }

    public void setTerminal_no(String terminal_no) {
        this.terminal_no = terminal_no;
    }

    public void setCashier_name(String cashier_name) {
        this.cashier_name = cashier_name;
    }
}
```

Should work.